# Multiple onclick button events Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to change an inputs value whenever one of my many "li" tags are clicked (without using jQuery). I listed two of the list tags in my HTML below and I want to differentiate between them in my if statement. What would I put inside the if parameters to display buttons[0] being clicked or buttons[1]?

```
function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById('values');
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  if(buttons[0]) {
    input.value = 0;
  }
  else if(buttons[1]) {
    input.value += 1;
  }
};
```

HTML :

```
<div class="box">
  <input id="values" type="text" placeholder="2017">
  <ul>
    <li onclick="myFunction()" id="1">C</li>
    <li onclick="myFunction()" id="2">1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes.

First, It is because of your if statement checks whether button[0] and button[1] are undefined.

Since button[0] is defined, it never goes to your second condition. So, your statement is just the same as:

```
function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById('values');
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  if(buttons[0]) {
    input.value = 0;
  }
  // the second if else is redundant because buttons[0] is not undefined
};
```

Second, input value is in string, so to increment, you need to parse it to integer. So for the fix:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var input = document.getElementById('values');
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  if(buttons[0].id === e.target.id) {
    input.value = 0;
  }
  else if(buttons[1].id === e.target.id) {
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
  }
};
```

And your html needs to change a bit, because the function needs to capture the click event:

```
<div class="box">
  <input id="values" type="text" placeholder="2017">
  <ul>
    <li onclick="myFunction(event)" id="1">C</li>
    <li onclick="myFunction(event)" id="2">1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this solved most of it! My way might not have been the most effective way to approach it (I'm new to JS), but I think I can build off of this answer

Answer (score 1):

Given `html` at Question, if `<li>` elements have an `id`, you can pass `this` to `myFunction`, use `id` of `li` element

```
  <li onclick="myFunction(this)" id="1">C</li>
  <li onclick="myFunction(this)" id="2">1</li>
```

```
  if(this.id === "1") {
    input.value = 0;
  }
  else if(this.id === "2") {
    input.value += 1;
  }
```

Comment: Why not just `<li onclick="document.getElementById('values').value = 0;" id="1">C</li>`?  Based on the OP's code this would be more concise as there's no point in the myFunction function when you think about it with it's current logic. Having said that, it's not the best approach when what should really be happening is the use of  a click event listener to handle things, and removing the onclick code defined in the li tag attributes.

Comment: _"Why not just <li onclick="document.getElementById('values').value = 0;" id="1">C</li>?"_ There could be other conditions? See Answer at _"Given html at Question"_.

Comment: True, but you're adding an additional if statement for each case which bloats things.

Answer (score 0):

I am somewhat confused as to what you want, but I think this should come pretty close? Let me know and I'm happy to help further.

**EDIT**: Just noticed you were calling this function from the element itself. Ignore this unless you want to abstract it, which I would usually suggest.

```
function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById('values');
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (i === 0) {
        input.value = 0;
      }
      else if(i === 1) {
        input.value += 1;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding events to each `<li>`, use [event delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm). Details are commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
// Reference the <ul>
var list = document.querySelector('ul');

// When list is clicked call function delegator()
list.addEventListener('click', delegator, false);

/* This function uses a pattern called event...
||...delegation. Basically we register the event...
||...on the parent of multiple clickable elements...
||...In this case it would be <ul> and the children...
||...<li> would be the last in an event chain...
||...which would make that particular <li>...
||...the event.target (the one that's clicked)...
||...Any other elements above event.target are...
||...event.currentTarget. By knowing this, we can...
||...determine event.target by determining what is...
||...event.currentTarget.
*/
function delegator(event) {
  // If it ain't event.currentTarget...
  if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) {
    /*...then it's gotta be event.target...
    ||...so let's store it's id in a var
    */
    var tgt = event.target.id;
    // Reference the id to as an DOM object
    var target = document.getElementById(tgt);
    // Get and store target's text
    var value = target.textContent;
    // Get and set textbox's value to the text of target
    document.getElementById('values').value = value;
  }

  return false;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <input id="values" type="text" placeholder="2017">
  <ul>
    <li id="i1">C</li>
    <li id="i2">1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```